# GCP : Fetch CloudRun URL via Python client API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I want to fetch a CloudRun service's URL via a Python client if its possible in GCP ?
Is there any API / sample code / python client that has the capability?

Any leads will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Raghav Arora

Comment: You can use the Cloud Run rest API to request the service information (like the URL) and then use it as you wish: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest

Comment: The error from the gcloud command means you used projectName rather than projectID.  Have you tried using the project ID instead?

Comment: Yes @GariSingh, I've already tried it via the above commands (listing the one for projectid below:
gcloud config set project <projectId>).

Still it doesn't recognise.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere, is there any Python library for these rest apis?
Just trying to avoid writing from scratch if something is already available to reference.

Comment: AFAIK, no, you have to call yourselves the APIs

Comment: Per @gari-singh, you must use Project ID not Project Name. You can list your projects' IDs and Names using `gcloud projects list`. The first column is the list of Project IDs.

Comment: Your `gcloud run services describe` will work as you show it if you use a valid Project ID. I use a variant of this command all the time to get a service's URL

Comment: There's a Google API Client library in Python to achieve this too. See [Cloud Run Admin API v2](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/run_v2.html) and [`list`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/run_v2.projects.locations.services.html#list). But note that the endpoint is region-specific with Cloud Run and so you can only enumerate by region.